# How can I add a scroll bar to ToolWindow created from JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, intellij-plugin

I am developing intellij IDEA plugin. In the Toolwindow which is created from jPanel, I want to add a scroll bar to Jpanel (ToolWindow). How can I do this ?

[Sample code fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3WSv.png)

Comment: !) Choose tags carefully. 2) Add code as text, not images. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).